# C# ASP.NET How To Add Multiple Version Of Newtonsof.Json into Web Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net

I had a web application which using NewtonSoft.Json version 6.0.0.0 and I would like to include my another project (Library classes) which using NewtonSoft.Json version 13.0.0.0. Program will crashed with below error when running the Library class in my Web application. I can't upgrade my Web Application NewtonSoft.Json version 6.0.0.0 to 13.0.0.0, this will caused the WebApplication crash due to Owin SignalR v2.1.0 which using v6. I had searched around and change the config assembly version as below in web.config (as per my finding) but it's still failed.

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

```xml
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0" />     
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Mike, I solved my problem by fallback my Newtonsoft.Json version to 6.0.8 in my webapps project that's running Owin SignalR service. Hope can give you some hints.